# Building a water jet cutter using Arduino, CNC shield and GRBL firmware

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, stepper-driver, cnc

I am building a water jet cutter using [Arduino Uno](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-uno-rev3) and [CNC shield](https://www.handsontec.com/dataspecs/cnc-3axis-shield.pdf) for control.
    The CNC shield uses [A4988](https://www.robotshop.com/media/files/pdf/datasheet-1182.pdf) drivers to control the stepper motors. I uploaded the [GRBL](https://github.com/grbl/grbl/wiki) (for this shield) firmware to the Arduino and got ready to use [Universal G-code Sender](https://winder.github.io/ugs_website/) to send g-code instructions that the machine will work on.
    Now my question is this: if I want to choose to work on *full step, half step or 1/16th step mode*, does the Arduino, shield or the GRBL firmware know what my option is? I am asking this in order to know if I can use another motor driver (if I choose full step and the GRBL handle it well then I can use [L297 driver](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00000063.pdf) for example, which only work on full and half step mode).
I hope I made it clear...

Comment: Rather than use bold you should hyperlink to the datasheets or project home pages. Most people aren't going to know what GRBL is, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any stepper controller won't know or care if the driver is using full step or some fractional micro-step. All it needs to know is the number of steps per unit distance. For Grbl this is configured in the $ parameters.

*Table 1. Default stepper configuration for GRBL 1.1.*

```
$100=250.000    X steps/mm
$101=250.000    Y steps/mm
$102=250.000    Z steps/mm
```

Reference: [Grbl 1.1 Configuration](https://github.com/gnea/grbl/wiki/Grbl-v1.1-Configuration).

> Grbl is a free, open source, high performance software for controlling the motion of machines that move, that make things, or that make things move, and will run on a straight Arduino. If the maker movement was an industry, Grbl would be the industry standard. *Source: [Grbl home](https://github.com/gnea/grbl/wiki)*.

Comment: I know but when UGS generates the G-code for 1/16th step mode while I am actually using full step mode, it will give me the wrong number of steps, right??

Comment: I'm not familiar with UGS and can't find the configuration settings on the website but I presume it's just a matter of configuring UGS and Grbl the same way. Can you point me to the UGS configuration page?

Comment: https://github.com/gnea/grbl/wiki/Grbl-v1.1-Configuration

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ssuoF2oXGg

Comment: Yuri, I already had a link to the Grbl configuration manual in my answer. You've linked to an 18 minute YouTube video. Why?

Comment: The video talks about UGS configuration, as you asked me.

Comment: OK, but sorry, I'm not going to watch that for you.

Comment: I brought it for you, because you asked, and don't worry it answered me.